# Bind an element in two forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Im using the ASPNET MVC 5 to develop a web app and i have a strongly typed view with two forms, the second one is showed just when the first one is submited ( via ajax ):

```
 @model DTO.UserDTO

 <form id="firstForm">      
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name) //need this property on both forms, in the second form just readonly with this input value.
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, string.Empty})
    <button type="submit" id="btnSearchName"></button>
  </form>

 //second form
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
      //other inputs with other properties in the UserDTO viewmodel
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Save" />
  }

  <script>
    $("#firstForm").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!$(this).valid()) {
                return false;
            }
            findName(); //ajax request
            return true; // if true, expand(show) the second form
        });
  </script>
```

On the **Controller** the Action for the second form:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save([Bind(Exclude = "Id")]UserDTO model)
    {
         //the modelstate fails here because the Name is within the Required Attribute and its on the first form.         
    }
```

So, the problem is that i need to pass the `Name` property to the `Save` action within its actual value that user input on the first form, how can i add a 'reflected' `Name` property on the second form too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that the user may change the value in the `name` control, that you don't need to change it in the second form and that you just need to send it along with its data. In this scenario, you need a hidden input in the second form, where the value of the `name` property will be stored:

```
<form id="firstForm">      
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { id = "yourNameInput" }) //need this property on both forms, in the second form just readonly with this input value.
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, string.Empty})
   <button type="submit" id="btnSearchName"></button>
</form>

//second form
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name, new { id = "yourHiddenInput" })

  //other inputs with other properties in the UserDTO viewmodel
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Save" />
}
```

When submitting the first form, copy the value of the `name` property in the hidden field of the second form:

```
<script>
$("#firstForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
            return false;
        }

        $("#yourHiddenInput").val($("#yourNameInput").val());

        findName(); //ajax request
        return true; // if true, expand(show) the second form
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it would be something like this. If the user can change the value of the property in the first form, what you recommend? I know that Knockout or AngularJS do two way binding, it could resolve this scenario. But does it worth to use this framework just to cover this scpeciefic situation?

Comment: Just for this scenario, it's not worth the overhead. My example copies the data from the first form (the value of the `name` input) into the second form. Therefore the information is not lost. You could also bind a handler on the `change` event but I don't see the point in updating the hidden field each time the other one changes.

Comment: I see, just one more thing, on the seccond form where you put a hiddenfor (YourProperty).Is  This 'YourProperty' a new property that i need to create to handle that value on the second form?

Comment: It's not really clear from your question where and what exactly you are posting with the second form. Is it the same model? If so, _why_? If not, what are you posting? If you're not posting the same model then you probably need a "special" property for that. If you're posting the same model, then you'll just write `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name, new { id = "yourHiddenInput" })`.

Comment: It is the same model for both forms.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Just out of curiosity, why are you posting the same model twice? Do you post on different locations?

Comment: Actually on the first form i just post the Name property, on the Action i have this: `ActionResult FindName(string name)` , im just using the model property to take advantage of the DataAnnotations.